# Is there a difference in the messages produced by Azure.Messaging.EventHubs vs WindowsAzure.ServiceBus?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have a producer writing messages to an Azure event hub, and a consumer reading the messages from the event hub. I upgraded the producer to .Net core, and in the process, switched from using the `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` package to `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs` to write messages to the event hub.

Events from the old producer are still being processed with no problem. However, when the consumer receives any message from the new producer, I found an exception being thrown by the event processor, before my events get processed.

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Diagnostics.Activity]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Diagnostics.Activity]'

This message is not displayed in the log output in Azure, but it does show up in Application Insights. **The exception is not thrown when I run on my local machine.**

This issue has been [reported as a bug](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-eventhubs-extension/issues/55) on the official Azure Functions EventHub repo. In the comments, users mention that the issue was introduced in version 4.1.0, and reverting to 4.0.1 fixed the issue.

I reverted to 4.0.1, and it stopped the exceptions from being thrown, but *there is still a difference between the old messages and the new messages*. I'm using `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions` for dependency injection. Whenever I receive a batch of entirely old messages, there is no problem. However, when I receive a batch containing new messages, **the dependency injection scope has no services configured**.

If I run the project locally, there is no issue. It is only when I deploy to the Azure Functions environment that I have these issues.

So far, I have:

- Deployed in debug mode instead of release
- Created a new Azure Function App and deployed fresh
- Changed the publish configuration from 'Framework Dependent' to 'Self Contained'
- Updated the publisher to use `Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs`, so that the publisher and consumer are using the same package

I've tried to think of what might be different between my local environment, and the Azure Functions environment, for me to see a difference in behaviour.

**Local**:

- dotnet sdk 3.1.301
- dotnet runtime 3.1.7

**Azure**:

- dotnet sdk 3.1.302
- dotnet runtime 3.1.6

Comment: This is pretty interesting. Are you able to reproduce this in a console app? Function app is just adding another layer of complexity. If there is an inter-op issue between both packages, then it should also reproduce in a console app.

Comment: Can you add a log at first line of ProcessEvents methods just to narrow down whether function is able to consume message or skipped in some logic down the line. Also make sure logging is indeed working in the Function.

Comment: Internally, the Azure Functions uses the `Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs` library for its integration.  The `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs` library is compatible with `Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs` in that sending and receiving in both directions across those libraries is supported and has been validated.  I agree with the suggestions made by Serkant and Krishnendu.   Additionally, I'd be interested in seeing the code that publishes the events to better understand the end-to-end scenario.

Comment: @SerkantKaraca I couldn't reproduce it in a console app. The Function App works locally, so I don't think it's an inter-op issue between the packages, I think it is more specific to the Azure Functions environment

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT I added a log at the start of each batch, and can confirm that logging is definitely working. I updated the consumer to contain no business logic, it just outputs the partition key (which is the id of the device that sent the event). No deserialization, no parsing, just looking at the partition key. The messages from the .Net Core producer are still missing when I do this

Comment: I suspect it's a EventHub connection configuration related issue at your function end. Check 3 things in your deployed function as per the code `[EventHubTrigger("events", Connection = "EventHub", ConsumerGroup = "%ConsumerGroup%")]` you shared above. 1. "events" is indeed the name of your eventhub within the namespace, 2. Connection name is "EventHub", so it should have an entry in app settings of function app in Azure portal with the same name. Value MUST be of a namespace connection string without entity path. 3. %ConsumerGroup% is env var, so it must be present in app settings with valid.

Comment: The reason I am asking this because I am sure after testing that there is no difference at the sender part between old and new SDK as long as your code is able to send to event hub. So trying to probe if the receiver function app in both cases are the same instance and not a new one you setup for testing with potential misconfiguration.

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT It is **definitely** not a problem with the connection configuration. None of the code and configuration on the consumer side has changed, **and it shouldn't need to**. Both the old .Net Framework producer and the new .Net Core producer are writing to the same event hub.

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT I've made some progress with my investigation, but I'm still having the same end result - the solution runs locally, but not in Azure. I'm convinced that the message format must be slightly different, since the issue is determined by which producer the messages came from. I will try to create a minimal solution to demonstrate this next week

Comment: Thanks for the update and addition of exception details in the question.

Comment: Reverting the consumer to `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs 4.0.1` and changing the publish profile to `<SelfContained>false</SelfContained>` has resolved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing the answer as per the comment by the original poster:

Reverting the consumer to `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs 4.0.1` and changing the publish profile to `<SelfContained>false</SelfContained>` has resolved the issue.

Comment: This does fix the issue, but it doesn't answer the original question of why there is a difference in the messages from `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` vs messages from `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs`

Answer (score 0):

We are also facing the same issue.

we are using the event hub and app insight dll in the code for the sending the data to the event hub.

At the receiver side, we have the azure function which triggered by the event hub msg with app insight.

Normally we have the System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource dll version is (4.5.0) which is the dependent of the event hub dll.

but we need to add System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource dll version 5.0.0 .

[added screnshot of the dll version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg3Vp.png)

adding the DiagnosticSource dll version 5.0.0  at sender side and receiver side issue get resolved for us and working fine